# Where can I find a good quick reference for learning C after years of C++?

Tags: c++, c, c99

I last used C professionally around 1997 IIRC. I've used a lot of C++ since then. Now, I find I need to use some C again.

One thing I'm sure of is that I can't just drop the obvious C++ features (e.g. classes) and expect everything to work. There are various less obvious syntax changes. I just don't remember what they are.

Is there a good reference for making that transition again, but returning to C? If it explains the changes in C99 (and later?) that's even better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As dirkgently suggests, Harbison and Steele is a good reference, but I don't find it useful to brush up on.  To retrain your mind, I have these suggestions:

1. Reread Kernighan and Ritchie
2. Optional: read Peter van der Linden's superb [*Expert C Programming: Deep C Secrets*](http://books.google.com/books?id=4vm2xK3yn34C&dq=van+der+linden+expert+c+programming&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=IAyTS6bKNY-VtgeC6ZDVCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CBYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=&f=false).
3. Don't forget libraries!  Look at P. J. Plauger's book *The Standard C Library*, or just go to http://dinkumware.com/ (Plauger's company) and browse their excellent documentation of the C99 libraries.
4. Standard C lacks data-structure libraries.  Fortunately there is an excellent, free 3rd-party library that fills several voids: Dave Hanson's [C Interfaces and Implementations](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/software/cii/).

Comment: +1 for the van der Linden recommendation.  It's really that good.

Answer (score 1):

Herbison and Steele: [C: A Reference Manual, Fifth Edition](http://www.careferencemanual.com/) may be of help w.r.t C99. Also, read up on the standard, the papers available at open-std.org. And finally, the compiler/tool-chain documentation you are plan to use. The latter puts everything in perspective -- as to how much you need to re-learn.

Comment: 560 pages seems a bit much for a "quick reference". I don't need to learn C from scratch. I was hoping for something with a few pages of the main gotchas - something to save me that first few hours of swearing as every other line of code turns out wrong, basically. Mind you, it turns out I don't have a single C book any more, so maybe that book makes sense. But it still seems a bit big. As for standards - yes, I probably should buy a few of those.

Comment: I don't think you'll need to read the whole of it. Having a book in hand helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not enough but a good starter : [C for C++ Programmers](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~iancooke/osstuff/ccc.html)

Comment: That looks like a good starting point - but I'm fairly sure it's not up to date. For example, it tells me not to use "//" for comments - I'm sure that's now valid in C. I was shocked by the sight of "<<" and ">>" in a list of unavailable features - until I realised it meant for streaming, not for bit-shifts.

Answer (score 1):

Not a book but read GTK+ source code. It may be fugly but it's got some of the best C source code I've ever read.

Comment: That'd be a big read - care to suggest a particularly interesting file or two?

Comment: Take a look at how GtkObject is implemented as well as the closures.

Answer (score 0):

[C for Programmers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471928518), by Leendert Ammeraal, is by far the best thing I have seen along these lines.  Unfortunately, it is almost 20 years old, hard to find, and (obviously) not up to date on C99.

Comment: He probably isn't using C99 if he's running into missing things other than classes and templates.

For example, C++ added inline functions, mid-scope variable declaration, and single-line comments, all of which got picked up by C but not by many embedded C compilers.  Even if he uses C99 part of the time, he'll appreciate knowing the gotchas present in classic C.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following link, I have found it good for reference:

```
http://www.techbooksforfree.com/ccpp.shtml
```

Also Sarafi Books or Books24x7, (you have access to both using either ACM or IEEE membership), are excellent references for technical books.

Also, nothing can beat the K&R:

```
http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0131103628

http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/013089592X
```

I think the above should give you enough reading material to last for a few weeks and you will emerge as an accomplished C programmer. All the Best. :-)